# Can't do sign in authentification integrate with keycloak

Tags: oracle-apex

When trying to authenticate, error ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL) occurs after entering the username and password from the keycloac side.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык